# Wrong display on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, html, django, pythonanywhere

I am running a django app on pythonanywhere. I tested it in local and everything was working just fine without any error.
However, on pythonanywhere, there is a problem on one of my pages. On it I have a button that changes the style of a part of the page (basically changing a rectangle from portrait to landscape). Everything else on that page works well, but when I click that button, nothing changes.

I dig and looked at the template I'm rendering before and after clicking, the template is correctly changed, but nothing changes on the screen.
I tried to reload the site from pythonanywhere and then refresh the page, the pages changes well.

I'have looked at the access log, the Error log and the Server log, none shows anything indicating any error.

I don't understand where the problem is.

Comment: Do you see any errors at all in the error log?  Also -- did you try to check Console and Network output in the Developer tools in the browser?

Comment: Here is most of my problem, there is no error in the error logs